# inputstream available() always return 0 in android studio while uploading azure blob

Tags: android, azure, inputstream, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

i was trying to upload photo blob in azure, this is the method that i try

```
private void UploadImage()
    {
        try {
            //photoURI is intent data straight from camera activity
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoURI);

            //this is the problem, the available() is always return zero
            int imageLength = imageStream.available();

            final Handler handler = new Handler();

            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        final String imageName = ImageManager.UploadImage(imageStream, imageLength);

                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(ReviewnTakePic.this, "Image Uploaded Successfully. Name = " + imageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) {
                        final String exceptionMessage = ex.getMessage();
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(ReviewnTakePic.this, exceptionMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }});
            th.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "fail to send!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and this is the manager

```
public class ImageManager {
    public static final String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"
            +"AccountName=blabla;"
            +"AccountKey=secret;"
            +"EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

    private static CloudBlobContainer getContainer() throws Exception {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount
                .parse(storageConnectionString);

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

        // Get a reference to a container.
        // The container name must be lower case
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("images");

        return container;
    }

    public static String UploadImage(InputStream image, int imageLength) throws Exception {
        CloudBlobContainer container = getContainer();

        container.createIfNotExists();

        String imageName = randomString(10);

        CloudBlockBlob imageBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(imageName);
        imageBlob.upload(image, imageLength);

        return imageName;

    }

    public static String[] ListImages() throws Exception {
        CloudBlobContainer container = getContainer();

        Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = container.listBlobs();

        LinkedList<String> blobNames = new LinkedList<>();
        for(ListBlobItem blob: blobs) {
            blobNames.add(((CloudBlockBlob) blob).getName());
        }

        return blobNames.toArray(new String[blobNames.size()]);
    }

    public static void GetImage(String name, OutputStream imageStream, long imageLength) throws Exception {
        CloudBlobContainer container = getContainer();

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(name);

        if(blob.exists()){
            blob.downloadAttributes();

            imageLength = blob.getProperties().getLength();

            blob.download(imageStream);
        }
    }

    static final String validChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

    static String randomString(int len ){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( len );
        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
            sb.append( validChars.charAt( rnd.nextInt(validChars.length()) ) );
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

the problem i've already google about that "available()" InputStream, but i don't understand a thing, many say that there's some occasion where the available() will return 0 when the datastream is blocked, it makes me confused, what is blocked?

can someone tell me the correct way to do this? i'm new in Android Development

UPDATE

to be honest i take this method from [Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-android-photo-uploader) which in the case it's use gallery picker, so i modified it to take the Uri directly from Camera intent, this is the content of the InputStream while it loads

```
content://com.example.android.fileprovider/test/test--05-08-2017--04-58-1026842566.jpg
```

and on the original project, the content is different

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%1234567
```

i hope my explanation is understandable, i see the difference, but i don't know how to work around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure using the correct uri of your `photoURi` with the prefix `file://`, and try the code below.

```
long size = 0L;
File file = new File(photoURI);
if(file.exists()) {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    size = fis.available();
    fis.close();
}
```